# Onclick não chama a função

Tags: javascript

Galera estou usando `webpack` e `babel` para usar as novas `features` do `ES6`, principalmente a parte de modularização o qual está funcionando perfeitamente e também estou usando um servidor de desenvolvimento. Acontece que por algum motivo no meu `index.html` o evento `onclick` não chama nenhuma função que eu especifico dentro dela:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-5" href="#" role="button" onclick="apostar()">
```

A Mensagem de erro que aparece no console do Browser é essa:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: apostar is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Estou usando `bundle.js` normalmente do `webpack`.

Answer (score 1):

acredito que a função `apostar` está definida em um arquivo `*.js` separado, assim como manda as boas prativas.

porém o mesmo deve está sendo minificado pelo `webpack`, e durante este processo as variáveis(incluindo as funções) são renomeadas.

O que aconselho, é que também aplique as boas praticas no seu arquivo `HTML` e não faça o bind de funções `inline`, ao invés disto, faça uso do bom e velho `addEventListener`.

Comment: No caso, o meu webpack está gerando o 'bundle.js' em memoria... Não está gerando o arquivo fisicamente no hd. Mas consigo abrir o 'bundle.js' em memoria atraves do console do Browser e a função apostar está lá minificada... Vou seguir as suas orientações !!!!! Te agradeço muito mesmo !!!!!!!!!!! Valeu !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, como o Lucas disse, pode ser que sua chamada não esteja surgindo efeito, coloque ela no final da página.

@section scripts{

```
@Scripts.Render("~/JS/Funcao")
```

}